# Trying to Get App's Price but Steam API Key Denies

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

i am trying to make a bot to get prices of steam games and save them on my database to do something later
but i am having a problem with steam api.
i use this:

```
https://partner.steam-api.com/ISteamEconomy/GetMarketPrices/v1/?key=MYAPIKEY&appid=552500
```

but i get this error:

```
Forbidden Access is denied. Retrying will not help. Please verify your key= parameter.
```

i use the right steam api key that i got at https://steamcommunity.com/dev/registerkey
but i got this error. i woud appreciate it if anyone could help me

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation for ISteamEconomy GetMarketPrices](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamEconomy#GetExportedAssetsForUser)

> NOTE: This call requires a publisher API key to use this method.

*This note can be found at the **bottom** of the section for each API endpoint that requires a publisher API key.*

They detail how to create a publish API key here:
https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview/auth

> 1. As a user with administrative rights in your Steamworks account, first visit your groups list.
> 2. From the list of groups, select or create a group that contains the App IDs for which you wish to have access with the WebAPI key.
> 3. Then click into that group to view the users and applications in that group.
> 4. If you have administrative permissions, you should then see the option to "Create WebAPI Key" on the right-hand side. Or you should see the key listed if it has already been created.

If, like me, you are not a game publisher, you will be unable to use this endpoint and will have to use the endpoints that do not require a publisher API key.